# Recovering data from Synology NAS – RAID5, ext4, "number of reserved GDT blocks insanely large"

Tags: linux, hard-drive, raid, ext4, raid-5

I have a 4-disk RAID5 array that had one of its four 3TB HDDs die. Being that RAID5 can tolerate a single drive failure, I'd like to try to operate the RAID5 without replacing the dead drive. (Run array with 3/4 drives)

I'm trying to recover the data in a Linux environment, using `mdadm` to assemble and mount the disks so that I can access the data, and offload it to other external storage.

When I `lsblk` I get the following:

```
NAME    MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE  MOUNTPOINT
sda       8:0    0 111.8G  0 disk
├─sda1    8:1    0 103.9G  0 part  /
├─sda2    8:2    0     1K  0 part
└─sda5    8:5    0   7.9G  0 part  [SWAP]
sdb       8:16   0   2.7T  0 disk
├─sdb1    8:17   0   2.4G  0 part
├─sdb2    8:18   0     2G  0 part
└─sdb3    8:19   0   2.7T  0 part
  └─md2   9:2    0   8.2T  0 raid5
sdc       8:32   0   2.7T  0 disk
├─sdc1    8:33   0   2.4G  0 part
├─sdc2    8:34   0     2G  0 part
└─sdc3    8:35   0   2.7T  0 part
  └─md2   9:2    0   8.2T  0 raid5
sdd       8:48   0   2.7T  0 disk
├─sdd1    8:49   0   2.4G  0 part
├─sdd2    8:50   0     2G  0 part
└─sdd3    8:51   0   2.7T  0 part
  └─md2   9:2    0   8.2T  0 raid5
```

The first drive is an SSD running the OS, the other 3 drives are part of the RAID5 array. The faulty drive has been removed. I can also tell which partition stores my NAS' data that I wanted recovered, based on the large size on the third partition of each drive. (`sdb3, sdc3, sdd3`)

I've tried assembling the drives using:
`mdadm --assemble --run /dev/md2 /dev/sd[bcd]3`

Which gives me: `/dev/md2 has been started with 3 drives (out of 4).`

I then tried:
`mount -t ext4 /dev/md2 /home/raid`

Which yields the error:

```
mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/md2,
       missing codepage or helper program, or other error

       In some cases useful info is found in syslog - try
       dmesg | tail or so.
```

I've read this is because there is no filesystem present, but these drives are from a Synology DS412+ NAS, which had a working filesystem on it, as they were being used for home network storage.

`dmesg | tail` gives an error of `Number of reserved GDT blocks insanely large: 8189`

Further research into this yielded this question
 https://askubuntu.com/questions/894530/insanely-large-gdt-blocks-with-mdadm-partitions whose answer links to a thread suggesting the issue might be the result of a patch to kernel version 4.7 which changes how GDT blocks are handled? A suggested solution is to use a version of Linux running a kernel pre-dating this update, noting 15.10 as their choice.

As suggested, I tried to run Ubuntu 15.10, but it didn't include `mdadm` by default, and I wasn't able to install it. I think this may be because 15.10 has reached end of life, and is no longer supported. Trying to install with `apt-get` has a bunch of 404 errors mixed in, and the install always fails.

It was suggested I try `file -s /dev/md2`, which returned a string of into I'm not sure how to transfer over without transferring over manually, but it described the Linux Rev ID, ext4 filesystem, the UUID, Volume Name, `(extents)`, `(large files)` and `(huge files)`

Is it possible, with only 3 of the 4 drives, to get the array accessible so that I can recover my data from it without replacing hardware?

Comment: First of all, note [the patch was for a reason](http://patchwork.ozlabs.org/patch/645035/); you may encounter "corrupt random kernel memory". But still this looks like the only working approach so far. If you succeed then please [you post an answer](https://superuser.com/help/self-answer). I have no experience with this and you will have just the right amount. Please note link-only answers are low quality. The answer should stay useful for future users with similar problems even after the linked thread is deleted for whatever reason; so cite and post exact commands. Good luck with recovering.

Comment: Your question/answer was of great help to me.  FYI I wrote a post on the [Synology community forum](https://community.synology.com/enu/forum/1/post/155289) because I saw lots of people there seemingly struggling with this.

Answer (score 2):

I had to use Ubuntu 15.10, and a work-around for installing `mdadm` on the end-of-life version in order to successfuly mount this array.

A patch in Linux Kernel 4.7 changed the way that Linux handles large GPT blocks, which is intended to avoid memory corruption, but also causes the RAID to fail mounting in cases like this.

I was able to mount the RAID array by switching to Ubuntu 15.10. However, `mdadm` is not installed by default on this version of Ubuntu, and because it's no longer being supported trying to download `mdadm` fails with 404 errors as the resources linked are no longer available.

To install `mdadm` on 15.10, follow the instructions here: [How to install software or upgrade from an old unsupported Ubuntu release?](https://askubuntu.com/q/91815)

From [one of the answers there](https://askubuntu.com/a/91821):

> The repositories for older releases that are not supported […] get moved to an archive server. There are repositories available at http://old-releases.ubuntu.com.
>
> […]
>
> If you want to continue using an outdated release then edit `/etc/apt/sources.list` and change `archive.ubuntu.com` and `security.ubuntu.com` to `old-releases.ubuntu.com`.
>
> You can do this with `sed`:
>
> `sudo sed -i -re 's/([a-z]{2}\.)?archive.ubuntu.com|security.ubuntu.com/old-releases.ubuntu.com/g' /etc/apt/sources.list`
>
> then update with:
>
> `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`

You can now install `mdadm` using

```
sudo apt-get install mdadm
```

Once installed, run the command:

```
sudo mdadm --assemble --run /dev/md2 /dev/sd[bcd]3`
```

(In my case, I point to `/dev/md2` since this is my RAID5, and then `/dev/sd[bcd]3` because `sdb3`, `sdc3`, and `sdd3` are the data partitions of each drive where my data is, as you can see in the table above. Change these according to your needs.)

(If you get an error about the drives being busy, or running, just run `sudo mdadm --stop /dev/md2`).

Next

```
sudo mount -t ext4 /dev/md2 /home/raid
```

(You may need to make this directory first with `sudo mkdir /home/raid`).

The array was then available in the `/home/raid` directory, where my data was accessible for backing up.